# how to configure nest.js bull with azure identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, nestjs

I am trying to connect azure redis cache using 'Azure Active Directory Token'.

I am using Nest.js Queue concept with Bull.

Below is the config code for Azure AD Token:

```
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import * as Redis from 'ioredis';
import { createClient } from "redis";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const redisScope = "acca5fbb-b7e4-4009-81f1-37e38fd66d78/.default";
let accessToken = await credential.getToken(redisScope);

const client = createClient({
  username: 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
  password: accessToken.token,
  url: `redis://xxxx-domain.redis.cache.windows.net:6380`,
  pingInterval: 100000,
  socket: {
    tls: true,
    keepAlive: 0
  },
});

client.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err));
await client.connect();
```

I need to know how to add the above config to Bull module. Below is the code for Bull:

```
const bullConfig = {
  useFactory: () => ({
    createClient: ?????????????
  }),
};

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRootAsync(bullConfig),
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: USER_EMBEDDED_DATA_UPDATE,
    })
  ],
  exports: [BullModule],
})
export class SharedBullModule { }
```

In Nest.js Queue documetaion, they have given like this:

```
createClient?: (type: enum('client', 'subscriber'), redisOpts?: RedisOpts) => redisClient,
```

But don't know how to put that createClient config in the above structure.

Need some valuable help.